# Stylesheet won't load properly (Child theme)

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm trying to work with child themes for my next project.

Here's my problem:
I'm using a @font-face for my h2-headings, and the custom font is visible on the main font page (but with no color), when I then click on the post title the custom font disappears (but adds color). See images below for visual example.

The wordpress-installation is on a subdirectory http://name.maindoman.com

[image: Main]
[image: Post]

The code:

functions.php

```
<?php
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
    function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
?>
```

style.css

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Sixteen Child
Theme URI: 
Description: Child theme for the Twenty Sixteen theme
Author URI: 
Template: twentysixteen
Version: 1.1
*/

body {
    color: pink;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'font name' !important;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: lightblue !important;

}

@font-face {
    font-family:'font name';
    src: url('http://url-to-the-fonts.com/font-file.eot');
    src: url('http://url-to-the-fonts.com/font-file.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('http://url-to-the-fonts.com/font-file.woff') format('woff'),
         url('http://url-to-the-fonts.com/font-file.svg#font-Bold') format('svg');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    unicode-range: U+000D-FB03;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To include styles from child theme directory use the following function.

```
<?php get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri

Comment: So should I replace my entire functions.php with this code?

Comment: Whenever you need any js or css file from child theme then you should use this and if you need to add any js or css from parent theme then you should use get_template_directory_uri()

Comment: Not really no. I'm a bit unsure where I should place the code. I've tried to include it in my header.php for the child theme, but to no prevail.